# MongoDB converting timestamp to local timezone while reading

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my Mongo record:

```
> db.SBIN.find({'timestamp': ISODate('2020-03-09T09:25:05Z')})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e65be19c71d4f0ee849d961"), "tradable" : true, "mode" : "full", "instrument_token" : 779521, "last_price" : 256.75, "last_quantity" : 100, "average_price" : 258.86, "volume" : 13474712, "buy_quantity" : 1695192, "sell_quantity" : 1640323, "ohlc" : { "open" : 260.05, "high" : 262.75, "low" : 254.9, "close" : 270.5 }, "change" : -5.0831792975970425, "last_trade_time" : ISODate("2020-03-09T09:25:05Z"), "oi" : 0, "oi_day_high" : 0, "oi_day_low" : 0, "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-03-09T09:25:05Z"), "depth" : { "buy" : [ { "quantity" : 816, "price" : 256.7, "orders" : 4 }, { "quantity" : 2398, "price" : 256.65, "orders" : 3 }, { "quantity" : 4396, "price" : 256.6, "orders" : 10 }, { "quantity" : 9061, "price" : 256.55, "orders" : 24 }, { "quantity" : 19278, "price" : 256.5, "orders" : 65 } ], "sell" : [ { "quantity" : 4357, "price" : 256.75, "orders" : 3 }, { "quantity" : 12605, "price" : 256.8, "orders" : 12 }, { "quantity" : 31416, "price" : 256.85, "orders" : 13 }, { "quantity" : 9974, "price" : 256.9, "orders" : 9 }, { "quantity" : 9756, "price" : 256.95, "orders" : 10 } ] } }
```

Please note, the Timestamp is **`"timestamp" : ISODate("2020-03-09T09:25:05Z")`** in above record.

However, when I try to read the `last_price` for a given `timestamp`, then MongoDB returns as below:

```
> db.SBIN.find({'timestamp': ISODate('2020-03-09T09:25:05Z')}).forEach(function(x) {print(x.timestamp,x.last_price)})
Mon Mar 09 2020 14:55:05 GMT+0530 (IST) 256.75
```

As we can see above, the timestamp returned is **`Mon Mar 09 2020 14:55:05 GMT+0530 (IST) 256.75`** which is exactly GMT+0530 of my local timezone. Please ignore the `256.75` value as it is the stock value.

**QUESTION:**
I do not want this time stamp conversion, I want Mongo to return the timestamp the way it is inserted.

1. Am I querying in a wrong way leading to this anomaly?
2. Is there any thing else wrong in my approach?
3. This issue is seen when I try to extract only specific fields using `forEach(function(x) ...`. Is anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: set the timezone in codebase... example in java `user.timezone=UTC`

Comment: Which tool/language do you use to run the command?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I am using `mongo shell` for querying. Anyway, I think by using `.toISOString()`, it seems to work as I explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
> db.SBIN.find({'timestamp': ISODate('2020-03-09T09:25:05Z')}).forEach(function(x) {print(x.last_trade_time.toISOString()," - ", x.last_price)})
2020-03-09T09:25:05.000Z  -  256.75
```

I added the **`.toISOString()`** function.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple print you don't need `forEach ... print(...)`.

Use the [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#find-projection) parameter:

```
db.SBIN.find(
   {'timestamp': ISODate('2020-03-09T09:25:05Z')},
   {
      _id: 0, 
      timestamp: 1, 
      last_trade_time: 1
   }
)
```

Otherwise use one of the format methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: I will definitely explore this approach further.